# Overwrite functiontimeout of host.json file using c# code in azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Actually I want to override `functiontimeout` setting in azure function app `host.json` with our own functiontimeout.

Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Seems like you already know that you can set the "functionTimeout" in the [host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json). 
Can you specify in which case you want to override parameter ?

Comment: Actually the function app host.json functiontimeout is maximum 5 mins.
but if u want change the time we should go to the portal with out going portal
we want to give ability to change the time from code it self means we give timeout  value from json file we pass that value to host.json so they can chnage through code level also this is what we want to implement breifly.

Comment: is there any Microsoft document links to this requirement means is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the "functionTimeout" in the [host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json)

> Value indicating the timeout duration for all functions.
>   In Dynamic SKUs, the valid range is from 1 second to 10 minutes and the
>   default value is 5 minutes. In Paid SKUs there is no limit and the
>   default is no timeout. 
>   "functionTimeout": "00:05:00",

An admin host api exists : [Admin-API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Admin-API) but according to the documentation updating the host file is not supported.

You can also look at the source code for this controller here : [HostController](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Controllers/HostController.cs)

Comment: In the above statement u mentioned "according to the documentation updating host file is not supported."
Can  u provide that documentation link?

Comment: The link is in my response => https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Admin-API

Comment: but that is git hub link am i right?
u mentioned a statement in your response "according to the documentation updating the host file is not supported".
can u provide any Microsoft documentation link regarding this?

Comment: you're right but from the official repository. I don't know any other documentation about this api except this wiki.

Comment: Host.json in azure function app and this api bothe are same?